# Boat Seat arrangement and booking like Redbus using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an android application for ferry boat seat booking, in which I need to implement the seat booking like Redbus. Please suggest me what is the best approach to implement the same.

Comment: the best approach is to study the behavior of that system and implement logic that does the exact same thing

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do when starting with a new language or framework is to follow the tutorial (which in this case would be [that one](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html)) and once I get the hang of it, just modify the tutorial app by adding my own features one by one.

If there is a backend (planned or existing) to which you will send booking requests, also make sure to talk to the backend developers early and test some requests as soon as possible, so you have a working app from the start and can sell tickets even if seats can't yet be selected and all that fancy stuff.

Sorry for the high-level answer that might better fit for software engineering or programmers stack exchange, but here we are.